# Blackberry: RadioButtonFiled and EditFiled in the same line doesn't show EditField?

Tags: blackberry

I have a RadioGroup and two RadioButtonField added in a VerticalFieldManager. I want put an EditField for the first RadioButtonField horizontally. For ex: I have two RadioButtonField as "Enter number here:" otherwise user can choose "Number from existing Database:" in the second RadioButtonsField. In the first field "Enter number here:" i need provide an EditField horizontally next to first RadioButtonField, for him to type. I am trying to put an EditField horizoally but it doesn't show EditField horizonatally to the first RadioButtonField. May i know how to do that (or) any samples to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do.  Create a HorizontalFieldManager to hold your first RadioButtonField and your EditField.  Then put this HorizontalFieldManager into your VerticalFieldManager so it will look something like this

```
VerticalFieldManager vert = new VerticalFieldManager();
HorizontalFieldManager line = new HorizontalFieldManager();
RadioButtonField btn1 = new RadioButtonField();
line.add(btn1);
BasicEditField editField = new BasicEditField();
line.add(editField);
vert.add(line);
RadioButtonField btn2 = new RadioButtonField();
vert.add(btn2);
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Thanks. But it is NOT coming to me as expected, it is still showing EditField after the RadioGroup is placed. May i know how do you add EditField position in this case? Thanks.

Comment: You don't use RadioButtonGroup() to add your RadioButtonField ? I was just wondering how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by overriding the Layout concept mentioned as per the following link:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/radiobuttonGroup-related-problem-in-storm/m-p/396407

Thanks to all.